# How to read XML data from a URL by using C# Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I write this code block on my windows 8.1 project it's working. But didn't work on my windows phone 8.1 project

```
  private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Uri url = new Uri("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(url.ToString());
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I downloaded the XML and Windows Phone doesn't support "ISO-8859-9".

Second, in order to use XDocument, you need to download the file and send the stream as a parameter to the Load method.

Here's an example:

```
public void LoadXML()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://thewindev.net/post-sitemap.xml"));
    if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var xmlStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
    }
}
```